# How to optimize this MySQL query? (CROSS JOIN, subquery)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, cross-join

I have a challenging question for MySQL experts.

I have a users permissions system with 4 tables:

1. `users (id | email | created_at)`
2. `permissions (id | responsibility_id | key | weight)`
3. `permission_user (id | permission_id | user_id)`
4. `responsibilities (id | key | weight)`

Users can have any number of permissions assigned and any permission can be granted to any number of users (many to many). Responsibilities are like groups for permissions, each permission belongs to exactly one responsibility. For example, one permission is called `update` with responsibility of `customers`. Another one would be `delete` with `orders` responsibility.

I need to get a full map of permissions per user, but only for those who have at least one permission granted. Results should be ordered by:

1. User's number of permissions from most to least
2. User's `created_at` column, oldest first
3. Responsibility's `weight`
4. Permission's `weight`

Example result set:

```
user_id | responsibility | permission | granted
-----------------------------------------------
      5 | customers      | create     |       1
      5 | customers      | update     |       1
      5 | orders         | create     |       1
      5 | orders         | update     |       1
      2 | customers      | create     |       0
      2 | customers      | delete     |       0
      2 | orders         | create     |       1
      2 | orders         | update     |       0
```

Let's say I have 10 users in database, but only two of them have any permissions granted. There are 4 permissions in total:

1. `create` of `customers` responsibility
2. `update` of `customers` responsibility
3. `create` of `orders` responsibility
4. `update` of `orders` responsibility.

That's why we have 8 records in results (2 users with any permission × 4 permissions). User with id = 5 is displayed first, because he's got more permissions. If there were any draws, the ones with older `created_at` date would go first. Permissions are always sorted by the weight of their responsibility and then by their own weight.

My question is, how to write **optimal** query for this case? I have already made one myself and it works good:

```
SELECT `users`.`id` AS `user_id`,
       `responsibilities`.`key` AS `responsibility`,
       `permissions`.`key` AS `permission`,
       !ISNULL(`permission_user`.`id`) AS `granted`
FROM `users`
CROSS JOIN `permissions`
JOIN `responsibilities`
  ON `responsibilities`.`id` = `permissions`.`responsibility_id`
LEFT JOIN `permission_user`
       ON `permission_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
      AND `permission_user`.`permission_id` = `permissions`.`id`
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `permission_user`
    WHERE `user_id` = `users`.`id`
) > 0
ORDER BY (
             SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM `permission_user`
             WHERE `user_id` = `users`.`id`
         ) DESC,
         `users`.`created_at` ASC,
         `responsibilities`.`weight` ASC,
         `permissions`.`weight` ASC
```

The problem is that I'm using the same subquery twice.

Can I do better? I count on you, MySQL experts!

--- EDIT ---

Thanks to Gordon Linoff's comment I made it use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT `users`.`email`,
       `responsibilities`.`key`,
       `permissions`.`key`,
       !ISNULL(`permission_user`.`id`) as `granted`,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM `permission_user`
           WHERE `user_id` = `users`.`id`
       ) AS `total_permissions`
FROM `users`
CROSS JOIN `permissions`
JOIN `responsibilities`
  ON `responsibilities`.`id` = `permissions`.`responsibility_id`
LEFT JOIN `permission_user`
       ON `permission_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
      AND `permission_user`.`permission_id` = `permissions`.`id`
HAVING `total_permissions` > 0
ORDER BY `total_permissions` DESC,
         `users`.`created_at` ASC,
         `responsibilities`.`weight` ASC,
         `permissions`.`weight` ASC
```

I was surprised to discover that `HAVING` can go alone without `GROUP BY`.

Can it now be improved for better performance?

Comment: Add the subquery to the `select` clause.  You can then filter using the alias in a `having` clause and also use the alias in the `order by`.

Comment: The where-clause makes sure there are permission_user rows, i.e. LEFT JOIN can be regular JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh Please read my question more carefully. I said I need to display ALL permissions, not only those that are granted. There are many NULLs needed out there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's it! I never knew I can use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`!

Comment: It's better to use _exists_ instead of _select count_ when you need to check for existance of at least one row.

Comment: @RudolfYurgenson Could you help me with implementing your idea?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient way to do this is:

```
SELECT u.email, r.`key`, r.`key`,
       !ISNULL(pu.id) as `granted`
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `permission_user` pu WHERE pu.user_id = u.id
       ) AS `total_permissions`
      FROM `users` u
     ) u CROSS JOIN
     permissions p JOIN 
     responsibilities r
     ON r.id = p.responsibility_id LEFT JOIN 
     permission_user pu
     ON pu.user_id = u.id AND
        pu.permission_id = p.id
WHERE u.total_permissions > 0
ORDER BY `total_permissions` DESC,
         `users`.`created_at` ASC,
         `responsibilities`.`weight` ASC,
         `permissions`.`weight` ASC;
```

This will run the subquery once per user, rather than once per user/permission combination (as both the modified query and the original query were doing).  This has two costs.  The first is the materialization of the subquery, so the data in the users table has to be read and written again.  Probably not a big deal, given everything else in the query.  The second is the loss of indexes on the `users` table.  Once again, with a `cross join`, indexes are (probably) not being used, so this is also minor.